# If statement on duplicate key

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert/update the `force_check` value to 1 only if the `department` column is different from the old one.
I'm using MySQL 8

So far I've tried this query, but it returns 0 rows affected

```
insert into user (id, department) values ('ABC', 'Dep1') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE force_check = IF(department <> VALUES(department), 1, force_check);
```

The current row is

```
| id    | department | force_check |
|-------|------------|-------------|
| "ABC" | null       | 0           |
```

and it should be updated to:

```
| id    | department | force_check |
|-------|------------|-------------|
| "ABC" | null       | 1           |
```

Comment: MySQL [test]> insert into user (id, department) values ('ABC', 'Dep1')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE force_check = IF(department <> VALUES(department), 1, force_check);
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.user' doesn't exist
MySQL [test]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is with `null` values: operator `<>` yields an undefined value when one of its operands is `null`, which might defeat your `IF` function.

We instead can use `<=>`, the null-safe equality operator:

```
insert into user (id, department) values ('ABC', 'Dep1') 
on duplicate key update 
force_check = case when department <=> values(department) then force_check else 1 end
```

Notes:

- I used `case` because it is standard SQL (`IF` would work too).
- Of course for this to work you need a unique key on `id`, so that the duplicates can be identified in the first place